# Include Other Objects in Sun Lens Flare Compositing Project

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I created a Sun Lens Flare project by nodes compositing.

If I add some objects to the scene, the problem is when rendered, those other objects are not showed.

Rendering with Cycles. How to include and view other objects in this scene?
Here's the attached blend file:

[Sun Lens Flare.blend](http://ubuntuone.com/7ALyGcFovffPpwPhMZ9zNn)

Comment: I mean when I add a e.g. cube on the 3D view scene, it cannot be viewed when rendered. The 3D view scene contains a circle, suppose it could view other objects that I place on the 3D view mode.

Comment: Thanks for a really quick reply. Here's a video recording about the problem that I am having right now. It should take a bit of time to download the file. Sorry because the file size is 26mb. http://ubuntuone.com/4E0T6ThTUtGztGl00CsE1O

Answer (score 1):

In the node editor, you just have to plug the input of `Composite` node into the `Add` node output :

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked! But can I get rid of the ugly white background? Because I want to add this lens flare to my future project. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @JimmyJommy Try enabling *Transparent* in *Render settings > Film*

Comment: I am really sorry but can you tell me where is the render settings? Do you mean Render Layers or something like that? I am really sorry because I am quite new to blender.

Comment: The render settings can be found in the properties panel, it's the tab with the little camera. See here: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Interface/Panels

Comment: @gandalf3 I checked transparent but it could not show up the lens flare. I want to use the lens flare as a filter so I can add to other projects.

Comment: @JimmyJommy Please ask for it in another question (after searching if the topic is not already covered)